# This for circle cannot delete every same elements in a list, I don't know why

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

```
a = [1, 2, 2]
value = 2 
for i in a:
 if i == value:
    a.remove(i)
```

I want to delete 2 same elements in a list.  But the result tells me I just delete one of them. when I debug it, I find it only cycle 2 times, not 3 as I wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) for a **1-line solution:**

```
In [2764]: a = [1, 2, 2]
In [2755]: value = 2

In [2768]: a = [i for i in a if i != value]

In [2769]: a
Out[2769]: [1]
```

You can write the above as :

```
ans = []
for i in a:
    if i <> value:
    ans.append(i)
```

OR, you can also use [filter](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/filter) to remove all occurrences:

**Python-2**

```
In [2778]: filter(lambda x: x!= value, a)
Out[2778]: [1]
```

**Python-3**

```
In [5]: list(filter(lambda x: x!= value, a))
Out[5]: [1]
```

Comment: The `list comprehension` method I wrote is basically a `for loop` only. Check my answer. I wrote the `for` equivalent of `list comprehension`. That is how you should write your for loop.

Comment: ok, maybe I should learn about this way

Answer (score 0):

Here you don't have to use a comparison to remove a certain value from list

Here is a little modification to your code:

```
a = [1, 2, 2]
value = 2

try:
    for i in a: a.remove (value)
except ValueError: pass

print (a)
```

Whenever the `remove ()` function couldn't find the value you are looking for, it will raise a value error: `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`. To eliminate this, surround it with a try except. That'll do the trick.

**However** there are more easier methods to use `remove ()` function. For an example you could use while loop.

Look at this code:

```
a = [1, 2, 2]
value = 2

while value in a:
    a.remove (value)

print (a)
```

Its far more easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot. By the way, I don't know why the code I wrote above by for-loop cannot work